# Regex allow reuse of literals between matches

Tags: regex

I want to make an array of results from a string like this one:

```
results|foofoofooresults|barbarbarbarresults|googoogoo
```

I can't seem to get regex to work right up to the edge of the next occurrence of "results|"

```
1.results|foofoofoo

2.results|barbarbar

3.results|googoogoo
```

Comment: Can you provde more details? There are several ways to solve your problem, but they are only applicable if we know what the exact situation is.

Answer (score 0):

got it with lookaround

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

For the examples you gave, this regex will work:

```
results\|(\w+)\1\1
```

I can't tell from your examples exactly what you are looking for, but there are several other possibilities, including:

```
results\|\w+{9}
results\|(\w{3})\1\1
results\|\w+?(?=results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
results\|.*?(?=results\||$)
```

This matches from one `results|` to the next (or end of string) using a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).